# Defining the position of a tabularx environment

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx, mdframed

In my report, I use a `tabularx` environment within a `mdframed` environment. I don't know why but I have to delete the `table` environment surrouding my `tabularx` environment when I want a table in my `mdframed`. Like this :

```
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3.8 cm}|X|}
Blablabla
\end{tabularx}
\end{mdframed}
```

The problem is that my table is floating within my `mdframed`. I don't know how to define the position of my `tabularx` ... I'm seeking the equivalent of [h] for `tabularx` environment...

I hope you will be able to help me. And I hope that my english is no too bad and you understand me.

My code as demanded in comment :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
L'établissement des composants des processus et systèmes d'information sont illustrés ci-dessous avec les exemples présentés au point \ref{ExempleProcess} page \pageref{ExempleProcess}. Seuls les composants important sont identifiés ci-dessous. Il est évident qu'une analyse réelle doit tenter d'être la plus exhaustive possible.
\subsubsection*{Exemple 1 : gestion des commandes téléphoniques}

\textbf{Composantes du processus d'affaires :}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3.8 cm}|X|}
\hline
Intrants et extrants
& Intrant : information relative aux besoins du client \\
& Extrants : information pour le processus d'analyse de la solvabilité (si le client est nouveau) ou ordre de préparation de commande \\                        
\hline
Sources et destinations
& Source : client \\
& Destinations : processus de d'analyse de la solvabilité (si le client est nouveau) ou entrepôt \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

BLABLABLA

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe put the `mdframed` environment *inside* your `table` environment? That is, `\begin{table}\begin{mdframed}\begin{tabularx}...`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: you're missing a `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @John Second that. @DescampsAu If you are using the table environment with [h] option, you might just want to have a caption to the table. You can easily do that with the [Caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package with the command `\captionof{table}{...}`. You can apply labels and backreferences.

Comment: @John : doesn't work... My frame is very far from the place I want.
Martin : what about caption ? I just want to use the [h] option of the table environment

Thank you.

Comment: @DescampsAu if you do not want a floating table, don't use a float.

Comment: @Martin Ok. I will search to know how to "unfloat" tabularx. Sorry but I am at the beginning of the Tex learning curve

Comment: @DescampsAu You do not need to unfloat `tabularx` as it is not floating at all. You just do not need the `table` environment. Your MWE looks alright to me, but I probably do not understand your question.

Comment: tabularx is just the same as tabular: it does not float: it just goes exactly where you put it. If you want a floating environment you need the table environment.

Comment: As the other comments make clear, as it stands this really doesn't seem to make any sense.